# User suggestions Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, controller, eloquent

I want to show user suggestions to the logged in user.

It should be displayed to users who the logged in user does not yet `follow` and which the `user` has not `blocked` and was `blocked`.

How can I query this accordingly?

Function:

```
$id = Auth::id();
$users = User::with('profile')->where('id', '!=', $id )->inRandomOrder()->get();
```

Relationship on Usermodel

```
 public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'leader_id', 'follower_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function followings()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'follower_id', 'leader_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function blockers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'blockers', 'leader_id', 'block_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function blockings()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'blockers', 'block_id', 'leader_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Table Blockers

```
Schema::create('blockers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('block_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('leader_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('block_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('leader_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Table Follower

```
Schema::create('followers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('follower_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('leader_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('leader_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [whereDoesntHave()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) query method, which will check against the absense of a relation.

Firstly, you will need to get the currently authenticated `user`'s `id`. Then which each check, you will need to pass this `id` to be used within the check.

Example:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;

$suggestions = User::whereDoesntHave('followers', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('follower_id', $user_id);
    })
    ->whereDoesntHave('blockings', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('block_id', $user_id);
    })
    ->whereDoesntHave('blockers', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('leader_id', $user_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: I do not understand it unfortunately, it shows me people which I am still following. And if I block a person, it still indicates it to me

Comment: Basically, you will be querying all users who are not followers, being blocker or blocking the current user. The `whereDoesntHave()` method checks the relationship attributes and will only return users `which` meet the query.

Comment: what did you mean with your last line with user_id?

Comment: Edited answer: I didn't see you were using the same table for `blockers` and `blockings`. Now changed to `leader_id`, which would mean any `users` who have blocked the current user.

Comment: if i use whereDoesntHave  after the first check it works, if i user OrwhereDoesntHave it works not

Comment: I do not get an error message. The queries do not work, and it shows me all the users

Comment: I've edited my answer, rather than doing or, we will just check where again so it keeps filtering the list of users down,

Answer (score 0):

as i found you have for relation in your UserModel follower, folloeing, blocker, blocking but you want to select users that dont have any relationship with this user, so use WhereDosentHave such as:

```
$users =User::where(id, $id)->WhereDoesntHave('followers')
                             ->ORwhereDoesntHave('following')
                             ->ORwhereDoesntHave('blocker')
                             ->ORwhereDoesntHave('blocking')
                              ->get();
```

i dont test it but i think that work just check name of relations

Comment: I do not understand it unfortunately, it shows me people which I am still following. And if I block a person, it still indicates it to me

Comment: every ORwhereDoesntHave  should replace with WhereDoesntHave, try it!